# SwiftUI List Selection: Have to Tap Twice to Deselect Item Initially

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

Why do you have to tap twice to deselect "Item 1"? Am I doing something wrong? If not, is there a workaround? It happens both in the simulator and on my iPhone.

Steps:

1. Tap "Item 1". Nothing happens. Do not tap another item first. Also, it only happens once so restart the app to retry.
2. Tap "Item 1" again. It is deselected.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedItems: Set<Int> = [1]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView { // Some apparent solutions do not work inside a NavigationView
            List(selection: $selectedItems) {
                Text("Item 1").tag(1)
                Text("Item 2").tag(2)
                Text("Item 3").tag(3)
            }.environment(\.editMode, Binding.constant(EditMode.active))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent the double-click issue, set the selection in `onAppear` **inside** the List:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedItems: Set<Int> = []
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView { // Some apparent solutions do not work inside a NavigationView
            List(selection: $selectedItems) {
                Text("Item 1").tag(1)
                Text("Item 2").tag(2)
                Text("Item 3").tag(3).onAppear() { // onAppear inside the List!
                    selectedItems = [1]
                }
            }.environment(\.editMode, Binding.constant(EditMode.active))
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this sample code sets the same selection on every onAppear. Depending on how your app should behave you will have to change it.

If you have a ForEach in your List, you can attach the onAppear to it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why, but it seems to be the access to .environment.
Using a classical @Environment var works for me:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var selectedItems: Set<Int> = [1]
    @Environment(\.editMode) var editMode
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List(selection: $selectedItems) {
            Text("Item 1").tag(1)
            Text("Item 2").tag(2)
            Text("Item 3").tag(3)
        }
//        .environment(\.editMode, Binding.constant(EditMode.active))
        
        // try this instead
        .onAppear {
            editMode?.wrappedValue = EditMode.active
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me within a NavigationView. An EditButton works but setting EditMode programmatically does not activate editing. Using DispatchQueue.main.async it works, but I do not know why.

Comment: The problem seems to be related to the ScenePhase (active, inactive, background). The missing selection controls appear when pressing the home button and reopening the app.

Comment: seems it has to first draw the view before it can activate the edit mode. So going with your idea of DispatchQueue and maybe a little delay time might be good.

Comment: I found that you can also keep the original `.environment(\.editMode, Binding...` and set selectedItems in onAppear with DispatchQueue.main.async. This prevents EditMode from being activated in other views (otherwise you have to implement onDisappear when using DispatchQueue).

Comment: Best solution: Attach onAppear to something inside the List (ForEach or in this case Text) and set the selection there (without DispatchQueue). Use the original `.environment(\.editMode, Binding...` on the List.